# Health Bar not 100% full

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a health bar that, on entering the frame, it decreases slightly and isnt full. How can I fix this? The "Should be" represents what I want it to look like. The "What it currently is" represents the problem I'm having.

Should be: [image]

What is currently is: [image]

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextDisplayMode;
import flash.text.TextExtent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import fl.motion.easing.Back;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;


public class healthBar extends MovieClip 
{

    public var maxHP:int = 670;
    public var currentHP:int = maxHP;
    public var percentHP:Number = currentHP / maxHP;

    public function healthBar() 
    {
            updateHealthBar();
    }
    public function updateHealthBar()
    {
        percentHP = currentHP / maxHP;
        scaleX = percentHP;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: where is `currentHP` coming from? What's the code that actually updates the display?

Comment: Make sure that healthBar is actually the same width as the MC in the background (that makes up the border). I know this sounds obvious, but your code is definitely correct. Is the border resized at any stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you have print statement that outputs the `percentHP` variable, does it, in fact, display the correct value? 1 in this case, I believe.

You could also manually set `scaleX` to 1 and see if that still yields a non-filled bar.

Depending on the results of the two tests, you can narrow the issue down to how `scaleX` is being used, or how `percentHP` updates.

Comment: It does print out 1. And setting the scaleX to 1 has no different effect.

Comment: You've just narrowed your issue to the actual implementation of the bar. I assume this is not your whole code. Would you mind posting the place where scaleX plays a role in changing the health bar?